# Can we have 2 HC12 on a single Arduino (1 to receive and other to transmit)?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm working on a project and I need to send 2 datas and receive them at the same time.

My question is: Is it possible to have 2 Arduinos both have 2 HC12 (total 4), because I want each Arduino to send and receive data at the same time.

It's hard for me to have 4 Arduinos.

Comment: You may have to provide a link to this HC12 thing you have.  If you're trying to use a particular library with them you should mention that library also.

Comment: Why do you want 2 HC-12s? I thought, that they are already working duplex

Comment: It would be good to know what is meant by "two datas".  Two connections? Two items? etc.

Comment: i'm using the arduino for a motor in an RC plane (1 arduino in the sky the other is on the ground), i want to control it's speed from the ground by an HC12 (send from ground and recive in the sky)  the other is to send me back number of rotations of the motor (sends from sky and receive from ground) so total 4 HC12 and 2 arduinos

Comment: @chrisl The HC-12 is actually half duplex but with a small buffer. For true full duplex you need two pairs of modules.

Comment: how can i know if mine is half or full duplex

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can - one on `Serial` pins 0/1 and the other using `SoftwareSerial` on any other pins. Note that the one on `SoftwareSerial` will interfere with the one on `Serial` as it disables interrupts while sending or receiving.

It may be better to use an Arduino which has multiple hardware serial ports. Maybe one of the Teensy boards would be better for your needs.

Alternatively if (and I am not familiar with the modules enough to know if this is right or not) they operate as a transparent serial bridge then you could connect one module to the TX pin for transmission and the other to the RX pin for reception - reading from serial receives from one, and writing to serial transmits through the other.

Also note that you will have to ensure that both pairs of modules are running on different channels to prevent interference between them.

Comment: thank you so much, this is really helpful! can i know if you have any codes that may be helpful

Comment: @shamsaalb No. As I say I'm not familiar with the modules. However they look like a transparent serial bridge, so whatever you `Serial.print` from one end will appear at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to connect your TX pin on the RX pin of one HC-12, and your RX pin on the TX pin of the other HC-12, and use separate channels for both HC-12. And then you do the same thing on the otherside, but you need of course, to reverse the channels - Et voila.

However, you might need to take precautions (distancing / shielding) to avoid your emitting HC-12 to parasite the channel of the nearby receiver.

By the way, it seems that one should refrain as much as possible to use SoftwareSerial, which is not robust enough for high speed and seems to cause data distortion.